# didExitRegion only called when entering different region

Tags: ios, ios7, core-location, cllocationmanager, geofencing

I'm working on an iOS 7 app which specifies a set of 5 regions along a route, and sends a notification when entering or exiting a region.
The regions are circular with a radius of 1km and they are not adjacent, but have several kilometers of space between them. A bit like this (the `O` is a circular region and the `-` the space between them):

```
O----O---O-------O---O-----O---O
```

I've done some testing driving around in my car and everything seems to be working properly, except for one thing. The `didExitRegion` call does not happen when I actually leave a region, but is only called when I enter a different region. The event log looks like this:

```
2013-10-17 07:58:56 Entered region A
2013-10-17 08:10:05 Exited region A
2013-10-17 08:10:05 Entered region B
2013-10-17 08:26:15 Entered region C
2013-10-17 08:26:15 Exited region B
2013-10-17 08:51:52 Exited region C
2013-10-17 08:51:52 Entered region D
2013-10-17 09:19:04 Entered region E
2013-10-17 09:19:04 Exited region D
```

Note that all exit events happen at the exact same time as the enter event for the next region.
I've been re-reading the API documentation and I did notice the comment `Only boundary crossings generate an event.` but I would think this still means an event should be triggered right at the moment you exit a region.

I'm using a CLLocationManager with default accuracy (`kCLLocationAccuracyBest`) and call `startMonitoringForRegion` once for each region I'm monitoring.

Does anyone know if the behavior I'm seeing is to be expected, or whether I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I fixed it, but I don't know what caused it.

I had all region monitoring logic including the CLLocationManagerDelegate methods on a single viewcontroller. I moved it all to a separate singleton of which I keep a reference on my AppDelegate and use notifications to allow the viewcontroller to update the view, and everything is working fine now.